# A matrix norm optimization problem involving matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to characterize the the matrix $X^*$ that solves the following optimization (that is an analytical or semi-analytical solution form).

\begin{equation}
X^*=\arg\min_X \| (A+X)^{-1}\|_F \quad\mbox{s.t.}\quad \|X\|_p=r , X \succeq 0
\end{equation}

$A$ and $X$ are both symmetric square matrices. In fact, $A$ is positive definite and $X$ is positive semi-definite. Here $\|.\|_F$ and $\|.\|_p$ are Frobenius and p-Schatten norms.

I am interested in $X^*$ when $p=1$ and $p=2$ (but even knowing the solution in one of these cases is still very helpful).

The problem statement itself looks simple, but I have not been able to characterize its solution. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Golabi

Comment: Why do you want the nonconvex constraint $\| X \|_{p}=r$?  would solutions with $\| X \|_{p} \leq r$ be sufficient?

Comment: No reason other than I was just not sure about that. If they would be provably equivalent in this specific problem, then please consider $\|X\|_p \leq r$ instead to keep it convex.

Comment: Similarly, would minimizing the 2-norm, $\| (A+X)^{-1} \|_{2}$, be acceptable?

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be Frobenius norm.

Comment: you can characterize the optimal solution via the KKT conditions, but it is unlikely you will get a closed form solution

Answer (score 0):

Presuming (as discussed in the question comments), the constraint is $\|X\|_p \le r$ rather than $\|X\|_p=r$, this can be numerically solved in CVX.

Formulation is described in http://ask.cvxr.com/t/represent-schatten-p-norm-in-cvx/649 .

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but by "characterizing" the solution I was referring to analytical or semi-analytical solution.

Comment: I will add that clarification to the problem description now.

Comment: @Golabi I think the characterization of the solution is whatever the numerical solution winds up being.I'm not optimistic you will get any more characterization than that.

Comment: Maybe there is no analytical solution, but I wanted to make sure. I was able to make some partial progress. If one can assume that $X^*$ and $A$ can be diagonalized by the same orthogonal matrix, then one can obtain a closed form expression by solving the Lagrangian. However, I am not sure if the optimal $X^*$ happens to necessarily satisfy the aforementioned assumption on the share diagonalizing matrix.

Comment: @Golabi It will satisfy that assumption if that is imposed as an additonal constraint, otherwise, I very much doubt it. On the other hand, if your technique is correctly applied, it would give an upper bound on the optimal objective value of the original problem, because you would be over-constraining, and therefore suboptimizing.

Comment: Thank you Mark! You are right. I already have that form as a solution that upper bounds the objective (and that is somewhat useful for the application I am working on). However, I am wondering if there is a tighter bound which can still admit an analytical expression. Or otherwise, whether I can say for what A's the optimal X happens to share the same orthogonal matrix. It seems you are pessimistic about such possibility. I will wait a bit more here to see if there are other opinions before I give up :)

Comment: If you start numerically solving some instances of this problem, it may help you gain insight, including formulating conjectures on the form and qualitiative properties of the solution.

Comment: You can also use your over-constrained upperbonuding solution as a starting (initial) solution to a numerical local or global optimizer.That might be very helpful if it is a fairly good solution relative to the original problem.